# I'm facing a 404 Not Found error when trying to register a user in my Ktor application

Tags: kotlin, backend, ktor, content-negotiation, ktor-client

When sending a POST request to register a user using Postman, a 404 Not Found error is encountered. The Ktor server logs indicate a failure in resolving routes with the message: "No matched subtrees found."

Trace Output:

```
TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [v1, users, register]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /(method:GET), segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(method:GET)
  /(method:POST), segment:0 -> FAILURE "Not all segments matched" @ /(method:POST)
Matched routes:
  No results
Route resolve result:
  FAILURE "No matched subtrees found" @ /
TRACE i.k.s.p.c.ContentNegotiation - Skipping response body transformation from HttpStatusCode to OutgoingContent for the POST /v1/users/register request because the HttpStatusCode type is ignored. See [ContentNegotiationConfig::ignoreType].
```

Additional Information: Endpoint Structure:

The project involves user authentication and note-related functionality. Endpoints include registration (/v1/users/register) and note operations (/v1/notes/create, /v1/notes/update, /v1/notes/delete). Routing Setup:

Routes are configured using the Ktor routing mechanism in multiple files (UserRoutes.kt, NoteRoutes.kt). The routes include authentication using JWT. Content Negotiation Issue:

The trace indicates a content negotiation issue: "Skipping response body transformation from HttpStatusCode to OutgoingContent." Potential Causes:

Mismatch in Accept headers in the request. Content type configuration in the application might be affecting negotiation. Ignoring HttpStatusCode type in content negotiation.

UserRoutes.kt:

```
package com.example.routes
import com.example.authentication.Jwt_Service
import com.example.data.model.LoginRequest
import com.example.data.model.RegistrationRequest
import com.example.data.model.SimpleResponse
import com.example.data.model.Userdata
import com.example.repository.repo
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.resources.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
const val API_VERSION = "v1"
const val USERS = "$API_VERSION/users"
const val REGISTER = "$USERS/register"
const val LOGIN = "$USERS/login"

@Resource(REGISTER)
class Registration

@Resource(LOGIN)
class Login

fun Route.UserRoutes(db: repo, jwtService: Jwt_Service, hash: (String) -> String){
    post<Registration> {
        val register_request = try {
            call.receive<RegistrationRequest>()
        }catch (e:Exception){
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, SimpleResponse(false,"Missing some fields"))
            return@post
        }
        try {
            val user = Userdata(register_request.email,register_request.name,register_request.password)
            db.addUser(user)
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK,SimpleResponse(success = true,jwtService.generateToken(user)))
        }catch (e:Exception){
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Conflict,SimpleResponse(success = false,"Some error occured!"))
        }
    }

//similar method for login
```

The project have a similar file for defining NoteRoutes as well where the concept of Authentication is also implemented

Authentication:

```
fun Application.configureAuthentication(){
log.info("Authentication started")
val jwtService = Jwt_Service()
val db = repo()
install(Authentication){
    jwt("jwt"){
        verifier(jwtService.verifier)
        realm = "Notify Server"
        validate {
            val payload = it.payload
            val email = payload.getClaim("email").asString()
            val user = db.findUser(email)
            user
        }
    }
}
```

Data class for User is defined as:

```
@Serializable
data class Userdata(
    val email: String,
    val name: String,
    val hashpassword: String
):Principal
```

cURL version of postman request:

```
curl --location 'localhost:8080/v1/users/register' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "email":"ayushkt@gmail.com",
    "name":"ayush",
    "password":"bvdsjc"
}'
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Community I've tried to trim the code and also add things which might be needed to understand the problem, please feel free to tell if this needs more trimming and bear with me as I'm new to Stackoverflow

Comment: Please rewrite your code by replacing the usage of the `Locations` plugin with the code for the `Resources` plugin (https://ktor.io/docs/type-safe-routing.html). The `Locations` plugin is deprecated and no longer supported.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman tried replacing Location as you suggested still facing the same issue

Comment: @AyushThakur It might make sense to also include your postman request (e.g. the `curl` version of it) here

Comment: Cool, but just in case you didn't think of it and your mail address is real: Posting it here might invite spammers and if the concrete address is not required to reproduce your issue, it probably is better practice to replace it with an example address like `your.name@example.com`

Comment: @greyhairredbear Hahaha....not the real one
btw are you able to identify the issue

Comment: Can you share the import for the `post<Registration>` method?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman i've added all import statements please check